# Image returned from FastAPI to Angular (12) application seems truncated

Tags: angular, png, filereader, fastapi

I am using Angular (12) to call a FastAPI REST-ful endpoint. The REST-ful endpoint returns an image that is generated by `matplotlib`. I noticed that when I use the OpenAPI interactive documentation to execute the call, the images are always complete; however, when I use Angular's `HttpClient`, sometimes (not all the time, but more frequently than not), I only get part of the image. What's troubling are the following observations.

- The behavior is intermittent. I cannot reproduce the issue in a deterministic way.
- Sometimes, when I visualize the returned image in Angular, and look at the network response body, I can see the image is good (FireFox) but incomplete when rendered using Angular.

Here is how I am generating an image in FastAPI.

```py
def get_image() -> bytes:
    matplotlib.use('agg')
    plt.style.use('ggplot')

    s = pd.Series([random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(1_000)])
    s = s.value_counts().sort_index()

    _, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 6))
    _ = s.plot(kind='bar')

    buf = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(buf)
    buf.seek(0)

    data = buf.read()
    return data
```

On the FastAPI routing side, here's my code.

```py
@router.post('/v1/image', response_class=Response, responses={200: {'content': {'image/png': {}}}})
def generate_image(file: UploadFile = File(...):
    data = get_image()
    return Response(content=data, media_type='image/png')
```

The Angular code is very tricky. First, I have to use `HttpClient` to get the data.

```js
public getImage(formData: FormData): Observable<any> {
  const url = 'http://localhost:8000/v1/image';
  return this.httpClient.post(url, formData, {observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob'});
}
```

Then, inside my component, I do the following.

```js
onSubmit(): void {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', this.formGroup.get('data'));

  this.myService.getImage(formData)
    .subscribe(
      r => {
        const fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.addEventListener('load', () => {
          this.imageData = fileReader.result;
        }, true);

        if (r) {
          fileReader.readAsDataURL(r.body);
        }
      },
      e => {
        console.error(e);
      }
    );
}
```

I bind the image data as follows.

```html
<img [src]="imageData" class="img-fluid" *ngIf="imageData"/>
```

I am not sure if the problem is with the FastAPI side or Angular side. When I log out `imageData`, it is just a base64 encoding of the image, and when I paste the content on an online base64 decoder, the image is "truncated". It seems only part of the image is either being returned from FastAPI or part of it is only being read back on Angular.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just a random input: are you sure that the javascript event triggers on the end of image loading and not the start? With small images, it can happen that the `start` event triggers the function, but in between the entire image has arrived because it's small enough. I'm not a javascript developer, so I don't know well the API...